# how to make drop downs and text boxes the same width with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using VB.Net MVC, Razor, Boostrap and Visual Studio 2013.  My clients would like the drop downs to be the same width as the text boxes.

My drop downs are created like this:

```
@<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>@Model.ListOfFields(i): </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-sm" type="button" 
                              id="@Model.ListOfFields(i)" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                              aria-expanded="true">

                     <span class="search" id="@Model.ListOfCategoryAttributeIDs(i)" ></span>
                     <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labeledby="@Model.ListOfFields(i)">

                    @For x As Integer = 0 To Model.ListOfDropDowns.Count - 1
                    Dim currentField As String = Model.ListOfFields(i)
                    Dim currentObject As CivilServiceInventoryMock.ViewModels.customDropDown = Model.ListOfDropDowns(x)

                    If (currentObject.fieldType).Equals(currentField) Then

                        Dim currentOption As String = currentObject.dropDownValue

                            @<li role="presentation">
                                <a id="ddListSelectItemType" class="ddListSelectItemType"
                                      onclick="lockValue(this)" role="menuitem" 
                                      tabindex="-1">
                                   <div class="itemOptions" id="@Model.ListOfCategoryAttributeIDs(i)">
                                       @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentOption)
                                   </div>
                                 </a>
                             </li>
                         End If
                         Next
                     </ul>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
```

My text box is created like this:

```
    @For i As Integer = 0 To Model.ListOfDisplayTypes.Count - 1
        If Model.ListOfDisplayTypes(i).Equals("TextBox") Then
        @<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <b>@Model.ListOfFields(i): </b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="search" id="@Model.ListOfCategoryAttributeIDs(i)" 
                      name="@Model.ListOfFields(i)" type="text" placeholder="@Model.ListOfFields(i)" />
            </div>
        </div>
        End If
    Next
```

I have added and played around with the following css but I have not found the correct combination to make the drop downs and text boxes the same width:

```
.btn-group {
    width:90%;
}
.btn-group .btn {
    width:90%;
    }
.btn-group .btn.dropdown-toggle {
    width:100%;
    }
.dropdown-menu {
    width:100%;
}
```

Is there some combination of column size and width percentage I should be using to make my drop downs and text boxes the same  width?

Answer (score 0):

Check Boostrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

In the form part you can set your form to class="form-inline" (it can be applied to a div that is grouping the content where the inputs are, doesnt need to be necessary a form).

After you have added the form-inline in the parent container group the inputs with  and should be the same size

```
@For i As Integer = 0 To Model.ListOfDisplayTypes.Count - 1
    If Model.ListOfDisplayTypes(i).Equals("TextBox") Then
    @<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <b>@Model.ListOfFields(i): </b>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input class="search" id="@Model.ListOfCategoryAttributeIDs(i)" 
                  name="@Model.ListOfFields(i)" type="text" placeholder="@Model.ListOfFields(i)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This is not working like I desire.  The drop downs are not the same width as the search boxes.  I did apply the form group to both the drop downs and search boxes

Comment: try with input group http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns

Comment: neither of these options are over riding the drop down auto sizing.  On top of that adding the input group to the drop downs made them automatically expanded.